# Discord Webhook with Rodecode

Tags: git, discord, webhooks, rhodecode

My goal is to get notifications on my Discord server when someone pushes on a specific repository on Rhodecode.
I created a Webhook in Discord settings, copied the URL and pasted it into the URL field from Rhodecode.
Do I need to do anything else? When I push into that repository, nothing happens on discord.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think discourd doesn't natively support format of rhodecode webhooks. It would need to create a special extension from rhodecode or use rcextensions to write the webhook in a format that discord server wants.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. It first didn't help me, but you may be right, because it looked different than GitHubs Webhooks (which are supported). I stopped looking at this problem, because there was also a permission problem, because the rodecode server is controlled through our university.